# How to get an image to fit along side my JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, turnjs

I need some help getting this running the way I want to, I'm very new to JavaScript and webdev in general. I want to get an image to display next to my javascript application that was written with Turn.js.

Here is my HTML code which I believe is right:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bandanaworld.com/20108.JPG" alt="img"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="t">
                <div class="tc rel">
                    <div class="book" id="book">
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/01.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/02.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/03.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/04.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/05.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="page"><img src="https://raw.github.com/blasten/turn.js/master/demos/magazine/pages/06.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've set up a JFiddle with an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gpheob5r/

Comment: Can you give a clearer description of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you wnat to achieve ("I want to get an image to display next to my javascript application" - what js-application?),
but looking at your html you're missing a closing  at line 5 (your first bootstrap-row)

Comment: Hey, I fixed the code.  Basically I want the book to be on the same row as the picture. For some reason it is not working.  Sorry if this is not an application, it's supposed to be working but it's based of [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/). Here is the new Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5v0Loo4a/